# Finding the number of vertices in this graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A graph $G_{n,k} = (V, E)$ for $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ ist defined by:

$V = \{M$ $|$ $M \subseteq [n] \text{ and } |M| = k\}$,

$E = \{\{v_1, v_2\}$ $|$ $v_1 \cap v_2 = \emptyset\}$ $\subseteq P_2(V)$

And now I would like to find out the number of vertices in this graph in dependence of $n$ and $k$. I stumbled upon this question while studying for an exam and I'm really at loss here because I don't see how any of the information given is helpful to finding the solution. I hope someone can help.

Comment: The number of vertices is the number of $k$-element subsets of $[n]$, which is $\binom{n}k$.

Comment: This is the Kneser graph. $KG_{n, k}$ is the graph whose vertices are the $k$-element subsets of $[n]$, with two vertices adjacent if they have empty intersection. The generalization of the Kneser graph is the Johnson graph, which has parameters $J(n, k, i)$ where $n$ and $k$ are the same as in the Kneser graph, and two vertices are adjacent if they share exactly $i$ common elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertices of $G_{n,k}$ are defined to be certain subsets of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$; specifically, they are the subsets of $[n]$ of cardinality $k$. The number of subsets of $[n]$ (or any other $n$-element set) that have cardinality $k$ is $\binom{n}k$, so $G_{n,k}$ has $\binom{n}k$ vertices.

The information given also suffices to determine the degree of each vertex of $G_{n,k}$. Let $M_0$ be a vertex of $G_{n,k}$; $M_0$ is a subset of $[n]$ of cardinality $k$. Let $M_1$ be another vertex of $G_{n,k}$; there is an edge $\{M_0,M_1\}$ between these two vertices if and only if $M_0\cap M_1=\varnothing$. Now $M_0\cap M_1=\varnothing$ if and only if $M_1\subseteq[n]\setminus M_0$, so the vertices adjacent to $M_0$ are precisely the $k$-element subsets of $[n]\setminus M_0$. The cardinality of the set $[n]\setminus M_0$ is $n-k$, so it has $\binom{n-k}k$ subsets of cardinality $k$. In other words, there are $\binom{n-k}k$ subsets of $[n]$ that have cardinality $k$ (and hence are vertices of $G_{n,k}$) *and* are disjoint from $M_0$ (so that in $G_{n,k}$ they are vertices adjacent to $M_0$). That is,

$$\deg_{G_{n,k}}M_0=\binom{n-k}k\;.$$

Finally, we can compute $|E|$, the number of edges in $G_{n,k}$, from the degree sum formula:

$$|E|=\frac12\sum_{v\in V}\deg_{G_{n,k}}v=\frac12\binom{n}k\binom{n-k}k=\frac12\binom{n}{k,k,n-2k}\;.$$